# TinyXML2/C++ - create empty element

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

I'm trying to create XML file with TinyXML2.

```
string _text = "<body><foo><foo2>text</foo2></foo></body>";
XMLElement *body = xmlDoc->NewElement("body");
body->SetText(_text.c_str());
```

Give me:

```
<body>
    &lt;body&gt;&lt;foo&gt;&lt;foo2&gt;text&lt;foo2/&gt;&lt;foo/&gt;&lt;body/&gt;
<body>
```

Is any way how to create empty element without top "body" and replace escape characters with <,>?

Comment: escape charackters solved: XMLDocument( bool processEntities = true, Whitespace = PRESERVE_WHITESPACE ) -> XMLDocument xmlDoc( false );

Answer (score 0):

You've created a top level element `<body>` then added another `<body>` element, with child elements, below it. You can't create an 'empty' element but you can add your string directly into an empty document:

```
XMLDocument doc;
doc .Parse ("<body><foo><foo2>text</foo2></foo></body>");
```